# Parented and Instanced Spotlights only render out the outline of their cone as light

Tags: lighting

https://imgur.com/a/pwomMTr

I parented green spotlights to instanced planes. These planes are instanced to the vertexes of a circle.

I did this because when I instanced the lights directly to the vertexes of the circle I got no lighting response whatsoever.

I built everything to scale and have this problem. In this image the scene is actually about 6 meters tall because I was trouble shooting to see if size was the issue.

I pushed the spotlight settings to see if something wasn't high or low enough. I went through my render settings. I tested this instance process in another project and it worked. I made all instances real but they don't work after that. I tested a lone spotlight and it worked. I messed with my HDRI and removed it for the base background and nothing changed.

I've tried as much as I can so I am hoping someone can help me out here. I would share the packed file but its too large for blend exchange. If I can do anything please let me know.

Thanks to anyone whose read this.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)